# Examples of features construction for linear methods in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: feature-selection, linear, reinforcement-learning

I am referring to page 210 of of Sutton and Barto book on Reinforcement Learning available here: [book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html)

Linear function approximation for *state-value* functions are of the form
$$\hat{v}(s,\mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}(s) =\sum_{i=1}^d w_ix_i(s)$$

Accordingly, linear function approximation for *action-value* functions are of the form

$$\hat{q}(s,a,\mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}(s,a) =\sum_{i=1}^d w_ix_i(s,a)$$

The functions $x_i(s)$ or $x_i(s,a)$ are called features of the state $s$ (or of the state-action couple $s,a$.
While I have found plenty of examples on how to choose features of the states, I haven't been able to find many references in the literature on how to choose features for state-action couples, and most of them are based on choosing features of the state $x_i(s)$ and then building the vector $\mathbf{x}(s,a)$ by simply assigning the state features in different slots of the feature vector, leaving other component at zero. To give an example, suppose we have only two actions $a_1,a_2$ available for each state $s$. Then, given the features vector for the state $\mathbf{x}(s)$, the features vector for the state-action couples becomes

$$\mathbf{x}(s,a_1)= \left[\begin{align}
                     &\mathbf{x}(s)\\
                     &\mathbf{0}
                    \end{align}\right]
$$

$$\mathbf{x}(s,a_2)= \left[\begin{align}
                     &\mathbf{0}\\
                     &\mathbf{x}(s)
                    \end{align}\right]
$$

My question is then: **can anybody help me to find references to different specifications of how to choose features for state-action couples?**